# how to add space when buttons change from horizontal to vertical layout on responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on this issue for a while and cannot seem to figure it out. Using bootstrap.

On my webpage, when I use a computer screen, my buttons appear side by side with a gap in between each button. This looks perfect.

Now when I view on a mobile screen, the buttons appear vertically, above one another which is what I want. The problem is that there is no space between the buttons. It seems like they're stuck together vertically and I have been trying to work out for a while how to create this space.

```
<a href="https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/xx-xx"> <button type="button" class="custombtn">View Our Workshop </button> </a>

<a href="courses/course-BRFAITC009"> <button type="button" class="custombtn">View Our Online Course</button> </a>

<button type="button" class="custombtn" id="checkout-button-sku_GtmnPXrxkiDt4F" role="link">Retake Online Examination</button>

</div>    

.course-btns {
     width: 100%;
     display: inline;

}

.custombtn {
    margin-right:1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .course-btns {
     display: block;
}
    .custombtn {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think for mobile screen you can use `max-width: 600px` instead of `min-width`, because `min-width: 600px` will target scree size upto 600px and `max-width: 600px` will target below `600px`

Answer (score 1):

Your media query would be `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}`